How do I fix 'Unexpected content at the end of chunk' in clickhouse?
I am trying to iterate two Resultsets from two connections simultaneously trying to merge two tables. This is how I get connection:
public static void execMany(Consumer<Connection> cons) {
    // ClickHouse server URL
    String url = "jdbc:clickhouse://myip:8123/db2";
    ClickHouseProperties properties = new ClickHouseProperties();
    properties.setSocketTimeout(6000000);
    properties.setSessionTimeout(6000000L);
    properties.setDatabase("db2");
    properties.setUser("default");
    properties.setPassword("12345");
    ClickHouseDataSource dataSource = new ClickHouseDataSource(url, properties);
    try (ClickHouseConnection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        cons.accept(connection);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

This is how I iterate:
        var ref = new Object() {
            long txCnt = 0;
            long addrCnt = 0;
        };
        var cnt = ClickHouse.count("transactions_tmp2");
        ClickHouse.execMany(conn -> ClickHouse.execMany(conn1 -> {
            try {
                var select1 = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM %s order by %s".formatted(t1,f1));
                var select2 = conn1.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM %s order by %s".formatted(t2,f2));
                String val2 = null;
                String val1 = null;
                while (true) {
                    if (ref.txCnt % 1000000 == 0)
                        System.out.println((ref.txCnt) + "/" + cnt + "=" + (1. * ref.txCnt / +cnt) + " addrCnt=" + ref.addrCnt + " fromAddress=" + val2 + " txAddress=" + val1);
                    if (val2 == null) {
                        if (!select2.next()) break;
                        ref.addrCnt++;
                        val2 = select2.getString(f2);
                    }
                    if (val1 == null) {
                        if (!select1.next()) break;
                        ref.txCnt++;
                        val1 = select1.getString(f1);
                    }
                    if (val1.compareTo(val2) < 0) {
                        val1 = null;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (val2.compareTo(val1) < 0) {
                        val2 = null;
                        continue;
                    }
                    assert val1.equals(val2);
                    cons.accept(select1,select2);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }));
    }

But suddenly I started getting this error, which I had never seen before:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Unexpected content at the end of chunk
    at me.nanosecond.TxImporter.lambda$merge$1(TxImporter.java:123)
    at me.nanosecond.ClickHouse.execMany(ClickHouse.java:291)
    at me.nanosecond.TxImporter.lambda$merge$2(TxImporter.java:78)
    at me.nanosecond.ClickHouse.execMany(ClickHouse.java:291)
    at me.nanosecond.TxImporter.merge(TxImporter.java:78)
    at me.nanosecond.TxImporter.main(TxImporter.java:185)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Unexpected content at the end of chunk
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.response.ClickHouseResultSet.hasNext(ClickHouseResultSet.java:164)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.response.ClickHouseResultSet.next(ClickHouseResultSet.java:200)
    at me.nanosecond.TxImporter.lambda$merge$1(TxImporter.java:90)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Unexpected content at the end of chunk
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:158)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.util.Utils.readFully(Utils.java:163)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.util.Utils.readFully(Utils.java:147)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.response.ClickHouseLZ4Stream.readNextBlock(ClickHouseLZ4Stream.java:102)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.response.ClickHouseLZ4Stream.checkNext(ClickHouseLZ4Stream.java:75)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.response.ClickHouseLZ4Stream.read(ClickHouseLZ4Stream.java:61)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.response.StreamSplitter.readFromStream(StreamSplitter.java:92)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.response.StreamSplitter.next(StreamSplitter.java:63)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.response.ClickHouseResultSet.hasNext(ClickHouseResultSet.java:149)
    ... 7 more

Both queries work well when executed one by one. Just in case someone asks why am I doing this, I'll redirect you to this question.

hi Stepan - I discussed your post here with the ClickHouse Integrations team. What version of clickhouse-java are you using here? The stack trace suggests that it is quite an old version. ClickHouse has been actively developing this library and it is greatly improved. Also, I'd note we have seen similar issues when timeouts occur due to long duration queries, and we have suggested increasing timeouts to avoid this situation: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/java#resolving-jdbc-timeout-on-large-inserts

@ThomO'Connor,, fixed by upgrading to last clickhouse jdbc, please post as an answer.

I discussed your post here with the ClickHouse Integrations team. What version of clickhouse-java are you using here? The stack trace suggests that it is quite an old version.
ClickHouse has been actively developing this library and it is greatly improved. Also, I'd note we have seen similar issues when timeouts occur due to long duration queries, and we have suggested increasing timeouts to avoid this situation: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/java#resolving-jdbc-timeout-on-large-inserts
